# swf file not playing aftre being published

Tags: flash, smartfoxserver

i am trying to run the 'connector' example that comes bundled with smartfoxserver2x downloads..there it connects to the server and loads the correct configuration file.
when i run it in adobe flash professional 5,it runs correctly and connects to the server but after being published as SWF movie,it doesnt work.it loads the configuration file but cant connect and gives error connection failure..ERROR 2048

this is the example i am talking about.
http://docs2x.smartfoxserver.com/ExamplesFlash/connector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2048 is a Security error. You probably just need to place your SWF in a trusted location. You can do that through the Flash Global Settings in the right-click menu, or via this web form: http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

It's usually best to create a folder containing all of your Flash projects and just give that directory permission, so you don't have to think about it again.